# Learning Architecture for Very Large Image Outputs?

Tags: neural-networks, image-processing

I have a large number of training examples $(x_i,y_i)$ where $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $y_i \in \mathbb{R}^{n^2 \times k}$, where $n$ is a number like $512$ and $k$ is a smaller number like 50.  You could imagine this, for example, as an image being mapped to a specific set of images or one much larger image.

I would like to know what (if any) learning architectures would be appropriate for learning a mapping between these input-output pairs, such that I can generate a predicted output "image" $y$ from a test input $x$.  I have looked at papers like [pix2pix](https://phillipi.github.io/pix2pix/), which capture the spirit of mapping one image to another, but (1) their inputs and outputs are of the same size, and (2) their outputs are rather small (e.g. 250k pixels vs. what I am proposing which might be 15M+ "pixels").

My understanding is that I would have to have one output neuron for each pixel in my output, which would make a network prohibitively expensive to store/train (right?).

I have also read about superresolution algorithms, which seem capable of producing pretty large outputs, but I am not sure whether that's appropriate for my use case since my outputs will be visually unrelated to my inputs.  But, perhaps I would be able to generate large-scale ($n^2 \times k$) outputs if I do something like chaining together a pix2pix-style network to learn a low-res output representation, then use a superresolution-style solution to upscale?

To summarize, I would like advice on whether the dimensions I am working with are feasible with any learning architecture, and if so, what are learning architectures worth pursuing for this type of problem.

Comment: Do you definitely need to generate everything in one shot? For instance, if you’re trying to cluster, you don’t need to generate the cluster—just its index. Or if you need to generate many images, you can instead condition on an integer 1...k and generate each separately. A lot of computational statistics is about adapting abstract approaches to computational practicalities.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  In my case, I do need the output to ultimately be a big $n^2 \times k$ matrix (whether that comes directly out of a network or whether I get some downsampled output that I then run some kind of upscaling/super-resolution on)...

Comment: My should have started with “Why…”, it seems.

Comment: The matrix I get will be used (as a matrix) in subsequent linear algebra operations.  I am not sure whether learning one column at a time would give significantly different results than learning all columns at once.  I guess I'm not sure what conditioning on an integer looks like in a network architecture; like would it be as simple as just creating $k$ different networks and train them using the $i^{th}$ columns of the output examples?